# Toast com problema

Tags: java, android

Sou novato em android,minha pergunta é boba,meu toast era apenas pra aparecer quando o usuario digitar a senha ou o email errado,mas ele aparece mesmo quando está correta, o que há de errado no meu código?

```
try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

            System.out.println(json.getString("resource"));
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json.getString("resource"));
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("Email : " + jsonObj.getString("tx_email"));
                System.out.println("Password : " + jsonObj.getString("password"));
                String email = jsonObj.getString("tx_email");
                String password = jsonObj.getString("password");
                if (mEmail.equals(email) && mPassword.equals(password)) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("result", result);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                else {


                   final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ou Senha invalido(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toast.cancel();
                        }
                    }, 250);
                }
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo seu `else` poderia ser trocado por:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ou Senha invalido(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).toast.show();
```

Você está colocando ele para ser mostrado depois de um tempo, mas a melhor maneira de tu fazer isso seria via [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), de uma olhada na documentação para tu poder fazer essa requisição de uma forma melhor.